# How to prove that $|a_{1}+2a_{2}+…+na_{n}| \leq 1.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1} ^{n}a_{k}\sin(kx)$$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $a_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$ for each $k=1,…,n.$ Suppose that $ \vert f(x)\vert \leq \vert \sin(x) \vert $ for every $x.$

Prove that $$\vert a_{1}+2a_{2}+…+na_{n} \vert \leq 1$$

Comment: You should've showed what you tried.

Answer (score 4):

As we have $\forall x, |f(x)| < |\sin(x)|$, we can consider this classical limit :

$$1 = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \geq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{|f(x)| }{x} $$

Then, by definition of $f$,

$$1 \geq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sin(kx)| }{x}$$

$$1 \geq \left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(kx)}{x} \right|$$

Finally

$$1 \geq \left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \times k\right|$$

Comment: Is $|f(x)|\leq |\sin x|,\ \forall x$ enough to conclude $|f(x)|\leq |\sin(kx)|,\ \forall x, \ \forall k > 0$?

Comment: Why do you need $|f(x)| \leq |\sin(kx)|$?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I understand now. The inequality in your comment brings the whole equation down.

Comment: I'll rewrite the answer as it was maybe a little too expeditive ;)

Comment: Thank you Tryss I never thought in using $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x}=1$

Comment: The trick here is to see that sin(kx) is about kx for x small enough. When you see that, dividing by x to get the inequality become natural